# Get Minimum date for all users in mysql

Tags: mysql

how to get the minimum created date per user_id? `sql_mode=only_full_group_by` is enabled

```
SELECT
    user_id,
    min(created_at)
FROM
    subscribers
GROUP BY
    created_at,
    user_id
GROUP BY
    user_id,
    created_at
HAVING
    MIN(DATE_FORMAT(created_at, '%Y-%m-%d')) > '2022-10-01'
```

Data is like this

| user_id | created_at |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | 2022-11-11 12:10:11 |
| 13 | 2021-10-11 12:10:11 |
| 12 | 2022-08-11 11:10:11 |
| 15 | 2022-08-11 11:10:11 |

Expected result

| user_id |
| --- |
| 13 |
| 12 |

Comment: ```sql_mode=only_full_group_by``` is enabled. I have tried using```any_value```  also just in case

Comment: @aDev see my updated ans

Comment: sorry @Asgar I modified the question

Comment: Please explain the logic for your result

Comment: This is actually a very long and complex query. I just want to get all user_id who's minimum date is less than the provided date so that I can join it to another query

Comment: @aDev, 12,13, and 15 have dates less than '2022-10-01'. What is the logic behind just 13 and 12 being the output?

Answer (score 1):

Just use `GROUP BY` for grouping your users and then use `MIN` to find the minimum date;

```
SELECT 
  d.`user_id`,
  MIN(d.`created_at`) 
FROM
  subscribers d 
GROUP BY d.`user_id`
```

If you want it in more sophisticated way, use:

```
SELECT 
  * ,
  (SELECT MIN(d1.created_at) FROM subscribers d1 WHERE d1.user_id=a.userId ) AS createdAt
FROM
  (SELECT 
   DISTINCT d.`user_id`  AS userId
   FROM
   subscribers d) a
```